# How to get text of element without it being visible in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, webdriverwait

I have a problem getting text from a table that can be shown by a button click, the data for that table are present even before the button be clicked, but when I try to get it, it returns nothing, if I try to push the button first, it successfully gets the text, is there a solution for this ? By the way, I am using Xpath to get the element.

```
table = f'(//div[child::table[child::tbody[child::tr[child::td[text()="Student Name:"]]]]])[{self.row}]'
self.studentName = self.dataBrowser.find_element(By.XPATH, table+'/table[1]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]').text
```

Comment: Hello Omar, If possible please share the URL and the code which you have written so that others can resolve the problem in your code.

Comment: sorry but I can't share the URL.

Comment: I just updated and gave the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you are missing a delay here.
I mean probably you are extracting the text from web element before it is fully loaded, containing it text content.
In several cases waiting for the visibility of the element you are extracting the text from will resolve your problem.
To give more precise answer we need to see all your code, including the page you are working on to make some debugging and testing.

Comment: ok I will try to wait for the elements

Comment: yes, you are correct, the elements weren't loaded, thx